# Magento Import Entity Type

Tags: magento, csv, import, entity

i would like to import a CSV file into a custom table from a local magento extension.
In order to do so, I would like to create a new "Entity Type" in the import/export module.

But it seems like this is not that easy, or at least I didn't find a tutorial or documentation while searching the web for some hours now.

Maybe it isn't even necessary to create a new entity type, but i thought it would be a good starting point.
As I am currently using magmi (sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) to import products, I would also take a solution to import data into custom tables with that.

Thanks in advance for every hint you got for me!

Best regards!

Comment: They way I have done it in the past is to import the csv via mysql or phpmyadmin then create a new module with a model with relates to your table, the bare bones is not too complex let me know if you want to me answer properly in this way, someone might have an easier method though.

Comment: @input could you guide me to import data to the custom module? I also suffered to doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting up a custom Dataflow profile. (System > Import/Export > Dataflow - Advanced Profiles)

There's a fairly simple example tutorial i've linked below which explains both the necessary Profile Actions XML, and also shows a simple example of writing your own dataflow adapter to handle the saving each row in your CSV.

http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/customizing-magento-dataflow-import-of-custom-data

Comment: The only problem with this is that advanced profiles don't handle the file upload for you, whereas normal profiles do.